# no value given for one or more required parameters?

Tags: vb.net

Please help me on this. I'm just a beginner and don't know what is wrong.

My ID is an autonumber, maybe that's missing?

```
        If TextBox3.Text = "APEL" Then

            Dim up As New OleDbCommand
            up.Connection = cn
            up.CommandText = "UPDATE APEL SET ID=@a, NME=@b, TOPIC=@c, DTE=@d where ID=@a"

            up.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@a", OleDbType.VarChar, 50))
            up.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@b", OleDbType.VarChar, 50))
            up.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@c", OleDbType.VarChar, 50))
            up.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@d", OleDbType.VarChar, 50))

            up.Prepare()

            up.Parameters("@a").Value = TextBox4.Text
            up.Parameters("@b").Value = TextBox1.Text
            up.Parameters("@c").Value = TextBox2.Text
            up.Parameters("@d").Value = TextBox6.Text

            up.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MsgBox("Data Updated!")
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            TextBox2.Text = ""
            TextBox3.Text = ""
            TextBox4.Text = ""
            TextBox6.Text = ""
            Me.Hide()

        End If
```

Comment: Since you are targetting WHERE ID=@a, you dont need to also SET Id.  But the error is because you have 5 params and only give a value for 4.  And yes, you should not try to update/set an AI PK.  When you fix the SQL you will also need to change the order you set the params

Comment: remove the ID=@a because autonumber columns are not supposed to be updated

Comment: thanks you so much..appreciated..but i use a another primary key rather than autonumber..